# Loop through set /p variable if there are not defined

Tags: batch-file

I need some help, how can loop through set /p for variables that are not setted or not being inputted. My code below is partially working except for the part that it will run an infinite loop if all the set /p variables are all inputted, I think it is because of calling the label inside a label

Here's what I want supposed you've asked for First Name and Last Name:

```
Enter First Name: 
Enter Last  Name: Bill
Enter 1 to Continue: 1
```

Now when it is processed and the batch detects that the first name is emptied it will go back and just prompts to those variables that are empty or not yet setted.

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set  name=
set age=
set gender=
set pick= "enter 1 to register: "

if %pick% EQU 1 goto getch

:getch
cls
if not  defined name (set /p name= "Enter name: ") else ( echo Name: !name!)
if not defined age (set /p age= "Enter age: ") else (echo Age: !age!)
if not defined gender (set /p gender= "Enter gender: ") else (echo Gender: !gender!)
goto getch
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second part you don't need to set a `VAR` that's already setted

```
@echo off

set  name=
set age=
set gender=


:getch
cls
if not  defined name (set /p name= "Enter name: ")
if not defined age (set /p age= "Enter age: ")
if not defined gender (set /p gender= "Enter gender: ")
pause
```

To be sure that all `VAR` will really be setted :

```
@echo off

set  name=
set age=
set gender=

:getch
cls
if not  defined name (set /p name= "Enter name: ")
if not  defined name goto:getch

if not defined age (set /p age= "Enter age: ")
if not  defined age goto:getch

if not defined gender (set /p gender= "Enter gender: ")
if not  defined gender goto:getch

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not defined gender (set /p gender= "Enter gender: ") else (echo Gender: !gender!)

IF DEFINED NAME IF DEFINED AGE IF DEFINED GENDER GOTO ALLDONE

goto getch

:ALLDONE
echo all done
```

Once you have *every* variable entered, then your original code will execute the `cls/echo` in a loop because there's no way to exit the loop.

Another, simpler way is to replace

```
goto getch
```

with

```
for %%a in (name age gender) do if not defined %%a goto getch
```

A third way is:

```
if not  defined name (set /p name= "Enter name: "&GOTO GETCH) else ( echo Name: %name%)
```

(and repeat for the other two variables) - then *remove* the final `goto getch`. What this will do is to display each value that *has* been entered and prompt for any that have *not* been entered. When the user responds, the code then re-executes the `cls` and displays the entries, stopping on any empty values. Note that `&` can be used to concatenate a sequence of commands.

BTW - `!var!` is not required in your `echo`es as you are not *changing* the value of the variables within the code block.

Also,

```
if "%pick%" EQU "1" goto getch
```

will afford some protection against unexpected user-input.